# Can Core Data perform multiple reads from a sqlite backed store?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In our app we are using core data and an nsfetchedesultscontroller in a table view. Some of our entities can have as many as 50k entries in them which is the same entity that is tied to the nsfetchedesultscontroller and table view.

My problem is that i have some background queries that execute a fetch on that entity (could take 3+ secs) while at the same time the nsfetchedesultscontroller is trying to execute a fetch on the same entity to fill the table view.

Right now if one of the bg queries are running the table view scrolling slows to a crawl. On the other hand if i am continuously scrolling then the bg queries do not run *until* i have stopped scrolling and presumably the nsfetchedesultscontroller has stopped accessing the entity/file system?

- Does this mean that core data will only honor one fetch request at a time and processes *all* read requests sequentially?
- Is Core Data locking the sqlite db while its running the query?
- Is there any way to improve this?

All of the bg queries are run in execution blocks using their own NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType context

```
NSBlockOperation *operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];   
[operation addExecutionBlock:^{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [context setUndoManager:nil];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[RootUtility getPersistentStoreCoordinator]];
    [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                             object:context];

// perform long running query 
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing. There seems to be a bottleneck between concurrent fetches as long as they are made using the main persistent store coordinator. My solution was to use this post:

[Can multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instances be connected to the same underlying SQLite persistent store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741513/can-multiple-nspersistentstorecoordinator-instances-be-connected-to-the-same-und)

and to create a separate core data stack on a background thread that shared only the NSPersistentStore. In this way, long fetches on this background stack didn't block the main thread.