# NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait: and dispatch_semaphore causing a deadlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an NSURLSession (with a delegate) that downloads some data. I do not want the method that initiates the download (`refresh`) to return until the delegate method has been executed. To do this I have a `dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.waitSemaphore, timeout)` at the end of `refresh`. `waitSemaphore` gets signalled at the end of the appropriate NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate method.

Inside that delegate method, I'm calling another method that invokes `performBlockAndWait` (quite a few times) on an NSManagedObjectContext. That MOC is setup with the `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. On the first call to `performBlockAndWait`, the app deadlocks. In the `performBlockAndWait` I'm doing a fetch request, with no other `performBlockAndWaits`.

The NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate methods are executed on their own NSOperationQueue. I do not create this queue, it is created by the NSURLSession. I am only encountering the aforementioned deadlock when I call `refresh` from the main thread. If I call it from another queue, it works as expected.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that whichever thread you create your core data stack (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and NSManagedObjectModel, etc.) on needs to be unlocked for data to be persisted or fetched because at some point in the save or retrieve from the persistent store, those operations are executed on that thread.

To dodge this issue, I created a second core data stack (ie. [Can multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instances be connected to the same underlying SQLite persistent store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741513/can-multiple-nspersistentstorecoordinator-instances-be-connected-to-the-same-und)) on a separate thread in order to keep the main thread free for specific fetch operations.